# Having trouble calling a stored procedure in php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am new the PHP. All I am trying to do right now is call a stored procedure from a MySQL server. I was able to successfully query the database with a standard SELECT statement but when I try calling a stored procedure it never works. If I swap $sql out for just standard SELECT * FROM table, it works. I have looked everywhere. But can't figure out what to do. Where am I going wrong?

```
    <?php
    $servername = server;
    $username = username;
    $password = password;
    $dbname = databasename;

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    else {
        echo "It worked!<br/><br/>";
    }

    if(mysqli_ping($conn) != null) {
        echo "Connection is open!<br/><br/>";

        $sql = "CALL GetUserTypes";

        $result = $conn->query("$sql");


        if ($result != null) {
            $i = 0;
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<p>' . $row['id']. "      " . $row['type'] . '</p>';
                $i++;
            }
        }
        elseif (is_null($result)) {
            echo "Something broke...<br/>";
        }
        else {
            echo "Query did not work...<br/>";
        }

        $con->close();

    else {
        echo "No connection...";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `CALL GetUserTypes()` ? Typo? Why isn't this in a try catch like http://i.imgur.com/DoeBHrZ.jpg

Comment: @Drew, that parenthesis is not mandate unless the proc accepts argument (non-optional)

Comment: Voting to close as no MCVE ... no error traps, plowing forward to next call

Comment: The line `$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)` will cause you to skip the first row of results in the `while` loop.

Comment: `$conn->query()` never returns `null`. For a query that returns a result set, it returns a `msyqli_result` object or `FALSE`.

Comment: @Barmar yep took that out and got the first line while sending a query. Still no luck with trying to call a stored procedure.

Comment: Which error message are you getting? When `$conn->query()` returns `false` you should use `echo $conn->error` to see the reason.

Comment: @Barmar "execute command denied to user ''@'localhost' for routine 'test.GetUserTypes'" is the error I get. In the MySQL database that I have the username I am using is does have EXECUTE rights

Comment: What does `SHOW GRANTS FOR user@localhost` say?